# How to order by and then arrange on the basis of common column element

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have one products table with 'sold','name' and 'mer_id' columns  , I want to arrange the products on the basis of qty sold and then group them if they have similar mer_id , this will ensure that the most sold product with other products of same mer_id appear together and at the top.

```
sold | mer_id | name
------------------------
6    |   7  | iphone
3    |   2  | ipad
1    |   7  | macbook air
5    |   3  | mackbook pro
6    |   2  | iwatch
```

Result I want:

```
sold | mer_id | name
------------------------
6    |   7  | iphone
1    |   7  | mackbook air
6    |   2  | iwatch
3    |   2  | ipad
5    |   3  | mackbook pro
```

I am not able to understand how to do this.

Comment: So a simple `ORDER BY mer_id, sold DESC`?

Comment: sir i want to show the merchant id having the most sold qty product first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to show the merchant id having the most sold qty product first

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from mytable
order by sum(sold) over(partition by mer_id) desc, sold desc
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by 
    (select sum(t1.sold) from mytable t1 where t1.mer_id = t.mer_id) desc, 
    sold desc
```

Comment: This is throwing syntax error that error in the statement near "over(partition by mer_id) desc, sold desc"

Comment: @aryanagarwal: you are running a version of MySQL that is earlier than 8.0. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is producing incorrect output everything is mixed

Comment: after order by sold  i want the products with same merchant id together this way i will have merchant id with highest qty sold products and its other product at the top, in similar way other rows will follow up

Comment: when sum is replaced by max I am getting the desired result , thank you !